# Bash prompt \w path prefixed with single chars only?

Tags: bash, shell, command-prompt

How can I change my bash prompt from these:

```
eric@mal:~/go/src/github.com/eduncan911/podcast/vendor/github.com/pkg/errors $
eric@mal:~/code/eduncan911.github.io/source/blog/archives/images/letsencrypt-ssl $
```

To a more succinct VIM-like buffer display like this:

```
eric@mal:~/g/s/g/e/p/v/g/p/errors $
eric@mal:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $
```

(I know, VIM buffers show the full filename and prefixes all directories.  but since in bash prompts we are talking about directories, I'd like to show the full name of the last directory.

There are a number of customizations here that I can figure out and include, like:

- prefix the directory with `~/` if within my home directory.
- suffix the path with the full name of the last directory path.
- hidden directories would use 2 chars and be shown as `/g/s/g/.a/.b./.c/x/y/z`

I believe I can figure out those tweaks.

I just don't know how to go about doing this efficiently in a Bash prompt.  Basically, how to get the paths dynamically, looping through each directory name, taking the first char prefix - unless it is the last directory in which we'll show the entire directory name.

`/tr;dr`

I work with very long directory names and it uses up the vast majority of my prompt.

I don't want to use `\W` as do I have multiple duplicated named directories.

`VIM` shows me an abbreviated path in the buffer name which works quite well for me:

Therefore, my goal is to replicate this in my bash prompt.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
function __prompt_get_dir {
  echo $(pwd | sed "s:$HOME/go/src/github.com/:/g/s/g/:" | sed "s:$HOME:~:" )
}
```

But that is just one and it won't scale well with all the different directories I want to shorten.

I'd imagine I need to loop through `$(pwd)`, split up each path based on `/`, take the first char, and rebuild a string.

But is there a more efficient way to doing that?  Some bash-zen I don't know?

I'd like to do this for all directories by default in my bash prompt.

Comment: Why not just `pwd | sed -E -e 's@/([^/])[^/]*@/\1@g'`

Comment: Or, to get the full name of the final directory: `{ pwd | sed -E -e 's@/([^/])[^/]*@/\1@g' -e 's/.$//' | tr -d \\n; basename $(pwd); }
`

Comment: very close. with `echo $( pwd | sed -E -e 's@/([^/])[^/]*@/\1@g' -e 's/.$//' | tr -d \\n; basename $(pwd); )` i get: `/U/e/g/s/g/e/p/v/g/p/errors`, but without `~` substitution.  i guess i can sed and replace that as well.  add this as an answer below.

Comment: came up with this `$( pwd | \
            sed -E -e 's@/([^/])[^/]*@/\1@g' -e 's/.$//' | tr -d \\n; basename $(pwd); ) | sed -E -e 's@^/U/(e|eric)/*@~/@g' ` which handles the home directory now. though still need to tweak it to remove "e|eric" and make it look for the logged in User instead.  that's another day. thanks!

Comment: @eduncan911, while that works too, it calls a whole bunch of external programs. It's not really a `bash` solution. Only `pwd` is built-in to bash. My answer, below, is entirely internal to the shell, with no pipes or external subshells, which might be preferable if you're sensitive to that sort of thing.

Comment: @ghoti correct. that's why i didn't mark it as an answer, a lot of externals.  but it was pretty short to get working, which others might be interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want?

```
nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

function __prompt_get_dir () {
  local path="$PWD"
  path="${path//~/\~}"
  local out=""
  local i=0
  for (( i=0; i<${#path}; i++ )); do
    case "${path:i:1}" in
      \~) out+="${path:i:1}" ;;
      /) out+="${path:i:2}"; continue ;;
      *) continue ;;
    esac
  done
  __abbrev_path="${out:0:-1}${path##*/}"
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="__prompt_get_dir"
export PS1="\u@\h:\$__abbrev_path $ "

nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $ pwd
/home/nicolaw/code/eduncan911.github.io/source/blog/archives/images/letsencrypt-ssl
nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $ echo $HOME
/home/nicolaw
nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $ echo ~
/home/nicolaw
nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $ cd ..
nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/images $ cd letsencrypt-ssl/
nicolaw@sansa:~/c/e/s/b/a/i/letsencrypt-ssl $
```

This should (I think) be fairly light weight, all things considered. It doesn't fork any external binaries and is pure bash so it should be relatively fast.

** Updated to use incorporate improvements from comments.

Comment: The entire variable is redundant; `HOME` is already defined (in fact, `~` expands to the value of `$HOME`).

Comment: Actually it forks out because of the command substitution, but you can work around that by making the function set a variable with a fixed name, referring to that in `PS1`, and then running the function in `PROMPT_COMMAND`. If it matters, that is... A nice solution, in any case!

Comment: @ilkkachu that's not great,... I always thought `bash` did "cleverness" to optimise out forking new processes if it's just calling a function or built-in? I need to RTFM again! :`-(

Comment: this worked!  will wait another day for any more bash gurus to chime in, just in case there's some secret formula.

Comment: @eduncan911 Are you sure it works how you want? It doesn't print `/` if you are in root dir and also prints `\~` if you are in the top level home dir.

Comment: @123 i see now.  you are correct it doesn't print `/` root.  home directory prints `~`. in the end, I just tweaked the output that if empty, display `/` and if only `~`, display `~/`. you can see my changes here: https://github.com/eduncan911/dotfiles/commit/8ffe78b5daa824c22c151f7bb11a256cc922629e#diff-97f59d80e017c0f9df14770586a6e3c7R77

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly then this should work

```
PS1=$'$(perl -e \'$p=$ENV{"PWD"};$p=~s/^$ENV{"HOME"}/~/;$p=~s{/(.)[^\/]+(?=/)}{/$1}g;print "$p\n" \')'
```

Runs one perl process and does some basic substitutions so I wouldn't imagine it is very resource intensive.

Bash function in case you are running on a toaster.

```
get_path(){
    x=()
    while read -r -d/ i;do 
        if [[ $i ]];then
            [[ $i = ~~ ]] && x+=("${i:0:1}") || x+=("/${i:0:1}")
        fi 
    done <<< "${PWD/~/~~/}"
    [[ $PWD != $HOME ]] && x+=("/${PWD##*/}")
    printf "%s" "${x[@]}"
}
```

Comment: This is quite a large overhead for a `bash` prompt (forking a copy of `perl` every time you press enter).

Comment: @Neech Not really, if this is causing you performance problems, then you have much bigger issues.

Comment: I suppose it's all relative, but I've been in many situations in a production environment trying to diagnose a problem when a slow bash prompt that forks external commands have just made matters worse. I guess I'm looking at this from a sysadmin PoV :-)

Comment: @Neech It's a single forked process... it takes 0.03 seconds on my system, by comparison your function takes 0.02.

Comment: Yup, but my point being was about in "sub-optimal" situations. If for example, you're on a machine that's suffering under load, you don't want to be performing upwards of 20 file stats and opens etc. every time you press enter on a command prompt.Anyway, both solutions work just fine and are perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Neech It doesn't perform upwards of 20 file stats though or anything remotely close, so not sure how that is relevant? My point being that you said it was quite a large overhead, which it isn't.

Comment: Relatively speaking, it is a large overhead. Stracing a stock `perl` on Xenial does 20+ file stats, and from my perspective and past experience, I would not enjoy that happening when I am diagnosing a performance issue on a production machine at shell prompt. Anyway, let us not get into an argument about it. It's all copasetic. :-)

Comment: @Neech You would get tons of stats running your function in strace, not really sure the point you are trying to make... Added a bash function anyway.

Comment: OP here.  I appreciate this discussion more than y'all know. I built my own POSHGit mimicking prompt years ago for Bash - and it was horribly slow. On macbook pro's, no issue.  But on remote systems, having to wait 1/2 second every time pressing return was insane. I lived with it though for its Git visual value - until the Raspberry Pi came out. Then the performance hit was now a blocker.  I've since rebuilt my bash prompt from the ground up to be extremely fast - in pure bash. I don't fork any longer. My prompt has git, virtualenv, rbenv and nodeenv statuses - and it's fast now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```
function crunch_pwd {
        local lpwd="$PWD"
        [[ $PWD = ${HOME}* ]] && lpwd="~${lpwd#$HOME}"
        while [[ $lpwd =~ (.*)(/[._]?[a-z0-9])[a-z0-9._-]+(/.*) ]]; do
                lpwd="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        done
        printf '%s' "$lpwd"
}
```

You then refer to this function in an escaped command substitution in your prompt. The `$PS1` variable gets re-evaluated every time the prompt needs to be displayed.

```
export PS1='\u@\h:$(crunch_pwd) \$ '
```

Personally, I like a more colourful version of the same thing:

```
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]$(crunch_pwd)\[\033[00m\] \$ '
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work as this is what I get: `~/g/s/github.com/eduncan911/p/v/github.com/p/errors` (note, that is not repeating - there are two "github.com" in my path, as the original path is: `~/go/src/github.com/eduncan911/podcast/vendor/github.com/pkg/errors`). not sure what `BASH_REMATCH` does.

Comment: Ah, the regular expression on the `while` line in the function was only stripping alpha characters, not periods or numerals. I've adjusted the function to handle your directories. Please try again. As for BASH_REMATCH, it's an array that captures the bracketed components of the most recently evaluated regular expression. it's described fairly well in the bash man page. Have a look!  :)